# How can I check if function exists on window.external

Tags: javascript, c#, window.external

How can I check if function exists on window.external?

I'm calling C# code from javascript and I want to check if a method exists in the C# object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the way,
Just using the 'in' operator like this:

```
if ('FunctionName' in window.external){
    window.external.FunctionName(...);
}
```